# Как можно связать номер телефона с абонентом в классе ?Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: c++, классы

```
    #pragma once
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <string.h>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    class Phone_number {
    
    public:
        string num = "";
        string code = "";
        string number = "";
        string type_number;
         string numbero = "";
         //Конструктор для копирование 
        Phone_number(const Phone_number& v) :
            code(v.code),
            number(v.number),
            type_number(v.type_number) {}
    
        const Phone_number& operator=(const Phone_number& v)
        {
            code = v.code;
            number = v.number;
            type_number = v.type_number;
            return v;
        }
        //Простой конструктор
        Phone_number(){}
    
        Phone_number(string numb, string num) {
            number = numb;
            code = num;
    
        }
    
        //Функция для ввода номера
        void Fun() {
    
            while (number.length() < 12 || number.length() > 12) {
                cout << "Nevirno nabraniy nomer ";
                cin >> number;
            }
            for (int i = 0; number.length() > i; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    cout << "(";
    
                }
                else {
                    if (i == 3) {
    
                        cout << ")";
                    }
                }
                cout << number[i];
                if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8) {
    
                    cout << "-";
                }
            }
        }
        //Функция для кода оператора
        void operato() {
            cout << endl;
            string num = "";
            num += number[2];
            num += number[3];
            num += number[4];
            if ((num == "050") || (num == "099") || (num == "095") || (num == "066") || (num == "089")) {
    
                cout << "MTS";
            }
            else
                if ((num == "096") || (num == "097") || (num == "098") || (num == "067") || (num == "068") || (num == "081")) {
                    cout << "Operator Kyivstar";
                }
        }
    
    
        //Функция для ввода нового номера + кода оператора
        void Print1() {
            cout << "\nEnter new number";
            while (numbero.length() < 12 || numbero.length() > 12) {
                
                cin >> numbero;
            }
            for (int i = 0; numbero.length() > i; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    cout << "(";
    
                }
                else {
                    if (i == 3) {
    
                        cout << ")";
                    }
                }
                cout << numbero[i];
                if (i == 4 || i == 6 || i == 8) {
    
                    cout << "-";
                }
            }
            num += number[2];
            num += number[3];
            num += number[4];
    
        }
        //Сетеры и Гетеры
        string Getnumber1() {
    
          
            return number;
           
    
        }
        string Setnumber1(string q,string a) {
            num = a;
            number = q;
        }
        void Print() {
            cout << "\nNumber - " << number << "\ncode - " << num << endl << endl;
    
        }
        string Getnumber() {
    
            return number;
            return num;
    
        }
        string Setnumber(string n, string g) {
            num = g;
            numbero = n;
        }
    };
    
    
    //Дочерный клас 
    class TelKniga : public Phone_number {
       //Конструктор по умолчанию
        TelKniga(){}
    public:
    
        
        TelKniga(string mo) {
            name = mo;
    
        }
        string name = "";
        void abonent() {
           
    
    
        }
        
    };


//main

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string.h>
#include <string>
#include "Phone_number1.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {

    cout << "Enter Telephone number" << endl;
   
    string some = " ";
    string s1 = "";
    string s2 = "";
    getline(cin, some);
   
    Phone_number Phone1(some, s1);
    Phone1.Fun();
    Phone1.operato();
    Phone1.Print1();
    Phone1.Print();


    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возьмите [`map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) и не мучайтесь. А вообще - вам надо говорить с преподавателем, потому что он явно хочет от вас чего-то одного, а тут вам могут насоветовать чего-то совсем другого...

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: @Harry, по вашему совету я связался с преподом и он сказал: 
В дочернем классе с фамилией можно использовать поле номера телефона из родительского класса. Только теперь у меня вопрос как можно использовать поле номера.

Comment: В потомке ваш открытый `number` из предка - просто как `number`.

Comment: Не особо понял. Мне типа его присвоить нужно ?

Comment: Я думал, вас интересует, как к нему обратиться - члену родительского класса в дочернем...